# State-machine from a class file?

Tags: uml, state-machine

I'm trying to draw a 'State machine diagram' for a class file, i do not understand how something like this works?

A class is a class, it does nothing, it is in NO state until a function within it is called?

I understand the concept entirely if it was actually diagramming a system.

Class:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you make a model that you don't know how it works? Use model to show your ideas and not to fulfill some kind of norm.

Class has no states itself, its instances might have some. Might have, not always! There are classes that are passive, that only have attributes that represent their "state". You should not make a state machine for a class that does not naturally have that kind of behavior.

Some example of classes whose objects have obvious states:

- CD player - OFF, ON, PLAYING, etc.
- Banc acoount - OPEN, BLOCKED, CLOSED, NEGATIVE, etc.

Can you identify some states of your Bid class? Maybe OPEN, IN EVALUATION, CLOSED, CANCELLED, etc.

There is nothing easier than drawing a state machine, once you understand its behavior. The real challenge is to achieve a sound understanding of this behavior.